# Compress multiple folders with Winrar command line and batch

Tags: command-line, batch, compression, rar, winrar

I want to compress all the folders that contain the word (Album), these folders have the following structure

```
Michael Jackson\Invincible (Album)
Michael Jackson\Thriller (Album)
Luciano Pavarotti\'O sole mio (Single)
Queen\Bohemian Rhapsody (Single)
```

So far I've tried this, but it doesn't work for me.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b /ad "*(Album)"') do (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -ep1 -idq -r -y %filename%
    echo %filename%
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot the problem as follows

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /s /b /ad "*(Album)"') do (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a "-cpNo compression" -ep1 -r -y "%%~nf.rar" "%%~f"
)
pause
```